# Adding integers and multiplying longs

Tags: java, list

I'll try to explain what I should do:

I have to generate a program that adds up integers and multiplies longs. Input is a `List<Integer> constants` and what I should get is `List<Formula> gatherResults`.  I should be able to add or multiply each element in the list with whatever number is given.

So let's say I have a list of integers [1, 2, 3], if I want to compute integers, I loop through the list and add something to each integer for example:

- the first integer is "1", so I want to add "7" and what I should get is "8", (1 + 7 = 8)
- second is 2, add 6 and get 8 -> 2 + 6 = 8;
- third is 3, add 5 and get 8 -> 3 + 5 = 8;

The same goes with longs, I have an integers list, but I need to convert those numbers to longs and multiply:

- number: 1 -> 1L, multiply with 5L and I should get 5L, (1L * 5L = 5L)
- number: 2 -> (convert to long) 2L multiply with 4L and get 8L -> 2L * 4L = 8L;
- number: 3 -> 3L multiply with 2L and get 6L -> 2L * 3L = 6L;

`FormulaGeneratorTest.java` shows exactly what this program should do and what I tried to describe.

Is anyone here to help me to figure out the logic for this?

Main class

*FormulaGenerator.java*

```
public class FormulaGenerator {
    
    public List<Formula> getFormulasFor(List<Integer> constants) {
        List<Formula> gatherResults = new LinkedList<>();

        return gatherResults;
    }
}
```

But I also have:

*Formula.java*

```
public interface Formula {

    int compute(int i);

    long compute(long l);

}
```

*FormulaGeneratorTest.java*

```
    @Test
    public void integersAreAddedAndLongsMultiplied() {

        FormulaGenerator formulaStore = new FormulaGenerator();

        List<Formula> formulas = formulaStore.getFormulasFor(List.of(1, 2, 3));

        assertThat(formulas.size(), is(3)); // one formula object for each constant

        assertThat(formulas.get(0).compute(2), is(3));   // 2 + 1
        assertThat(formulas.get(0).compute(2L), is(2L)); // 2 * 1

        assertThat(formulas.get(1).compute(2), is(4));   // 2 + 2
        assertThat(formulas.get(1).compute(2L), is(4L)); // 2 * 2

        assertThat(formulas.get(2).compute(2), is(5));   // 2 + 3
        assertThat(formulas.get(2).compute(2L), is(6L)); // 2 * 3
    }
```

Comment: What is your output? Does your program have an error? What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: Where are you stuck? You've shown your requirements, but not where you're having problems. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an implementation for `Formula` interface.

```java
public class FormulaOne implements Formula {
    private int value;

    public FormulaOne(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public int compute(int i) {
        return value + i;
    }

    public long compute(long i) {
        return (long)value * i;
    }

}
```

Then inside the `getFormulasFor` create object of the above class using the constructor and add to your list.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define an implementation of your interface `Formula`

in your class `FormulaGenerator` you should iterate through each element of your integers and add your formula Implementation to your list.

```
public class FormulaGenerator {

    public List<Formula> getFormulasFor(List<Integer> constants) {
        List<Formula> gatherResults = new LinkedList<>();
        constants.stream().forEach((Integer integer) -> gatherResults.add(new Formula() {

            @Override
            public long compute(long l) {
                return integer * l;
            }

            @Override
            public int compute(int i) {

                return integer + i;
            }
        }));
        return gatherResults;
    }
}
```

as you can see I return an anonymous object each time I get an integer from my stream.